# DoubleKey Map Implement Issue

Tags: java, dictionary

Is there a concise approach to generate DoubleKey Map in Java. I found several answers here, but none can fit my requirement.

Requirement:

Let's say K1,K2,V

1. only by given K1,K2 can target a unique value. By which means creating the following does not work.

   ```
   Map<K2, K1> m2;
   Map<K1, V>  m1;//here K1 needs have multiple V's.
   ```
2. If searching by K1, it should give a `Map<K2,V>`, vice versa.

The only thing I can do, is creating

```
Map<K1,Map<K2,V>>
Map<K2,Map<K1,V>>
```

And maintain both every time. code seems to be tedious.

Even if by using this merely solution, once scale up to triple Key Map, it will be a disaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If third-party libraries are fair game, this sounds like Guava's [`Table`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) would be perfect.  `Table<R, C, V>` represents a table with a "row" key and a "column" key.  You can use `get(row, column)` to get a value based on both keys, or you can use `row(r)` or `column(c)` to get a `Map` for the appropriate row or column, or you can use `rowMap()` to get a `Map<R, Map<C, V>>` or `columnMap()` to get a `Map<C, Map<R, V>>`.

If you can't use third-party libraries, then you're not going to be able to find a better solution than the nested `Map` solution you've already mentioned.

Comment: can you tell me more about the triple key map in Guava cuz finally i need this kinda map. Seems Guava only has 2 dimension (row,column) as mentioned in your answer. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: There is none.  If you need to be able to query with arbitrary combinations of keys, you should probably be using an all-up database; if there are only a few combinations you'll need to query on, you might be able to get away with a `Table<K1, K2, Map<K3, V>>` -- but there's a point at which things just don't scale as nicely.

Comment: seems to be the only suitable approach currently. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you make an object and use that as the key for your map.
Your object will contain k1 and k2.

```
public class MyObject{
K1, K2;
public MyObject(K1, K2){ this.K1= K1; this.K2=K2; }
}
@Override public int hashCode(){}// implement hashCode...
@Override public boolean equals()// implement equals
}

Map<MyObject, V> map = new HashMap<MyObject, V>();
map.put(new MyObject(K1,K2), V);
```

Note the code above is just pen and paper so you will need to add something to make it compile

Comment: then how about searching by only one key, say k2?

Comment: What do you want the result to be when you search by 1 key?

Comment: As listed above, if searching by k1, it should return me a map of <K2,V>

Comment: create a class that implements Map and adds your desired behavior? ill try to edit the answer.

Comment: what do you mean by then? I didn't quite get you.

Comment: The Map data structure doesn't support the functionality that you want , so you have a few options: 1 use more than 1 structure, 2 use a different structure, 3 make a new structure. How many keys do you plan to scale to?

Comment: Supposed to be triple key at most currently.

Comment: Maybe you need a database :), extending the collections framework might take a while longer than what you want.